# Facebook user email permissions working only for developer and not users

Tags: android, facebook, email, facebook-graph-api, cordova

I've integrated facebook login for my android app  , and the problem I'm facing is , when I login using my gmail id (im also logged in as fb developer , and using this mail id I created my fb app) I'm able to get my email address , but when I use other fb user's credentials , I'm not able to get their email. I get it as 'null'. I use facebook sdk 3.6 and use facebook connect for cordova. Could someone give me a step-by-step solution? i've tried all the methods what the stackoverflow users have mentioned previously, but nothing seems to work. Am I missing something? I've also set my access token from my fb app and set permissions to email. but it seems to work only with my ID and not others.
Please Help ASAP.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is not your fault some facebook account` Account Settings`==> `Privacy Settings and Tools` and `Who can look you up using the email address you provided?` this setting put `friends` that's why email value  is null

Comment: My other id is in public mode only , yet i cant use the other email id , or my frend's email id

Comment: am also facing same issue some facebook accounts not providing email....